# change listview on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I would like to change the listview template on a button click event. for example if your in edittemplate i would like to switch to ItemTemplate.

i am trying to do this because im writing my own custom update function for the list view. so after i successfully update the row, it doesn't switch back to the default view.

Rgds
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Adrian,
As you have tagged this as an asp.net question I would direct your attention to jquery (jquery.com). If you use a vanilla template (wrapping your elements in simple "div" tags) and use the jquery tools to do addClass/removeClass and toggleClass and apply various css styles to achieve the visual effect you desire you should be able to land just were you wish.

Using page methods you can leverage your custom update on a partial postback from jquery and reduce the server impact.

If you would rather do this server side you are probable looking to leverage the item databound event to set your template.

A more complete answer would require more information about what you are trying to accomplish.

Cheers,

CEC

Comment: Thanks CEC, at this time i am looking for a server side solution, not to say i didn't love your jquery idea, which i think is a brilliant idea too.                                              what i am trying to do exactly is, i have written my own update function, so when the user clicks on the update button in the list view, my update function gets called and not the default update. the problem i am having is once the event is called and everything is ok, i want to change to Itemtemplate view from editemplate. this is the part im stuck at ......